# I Am Confused - Why Won't This Fill? - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

[image]

Hi, I am a newb using Illustrator. I don't know what's going on in Layers )= I understand the tools, but not how they work together I guess.

It's black, but I can not see anything being filled.

What are the proper tools to use to make this kind of shape and get it to fill with colors in sections? Thank you!!

I selected all and attempted to live paint but I got this:

[image]

Comment: The Live Paint issue is a different issue. My original answer may have been incorrect I didn't notice the outline mode until i looked more closely at your screenshot. You may or may not *actually* need Live Paint.

Comment: Ahh ok. Do you happen to know what is meant by 'clipping paths'? I did cut the paths...does that make the live paint function not work?

Comment: There are many things which Live Paint won't allow. It's difficult to be precise without examining the file, but that's off topic really.

Answer (score 2):

The document appears to be in **Outline Mode**.

[image]

**Outline Mode** shows the spines of paths in order to more easily view construction. It doesn't show fills or color.

Switch to **Preview Mode** (View menu), if you wish to see fills and colors.

You may have inadvertently hit the shortcut for Outline Mode (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>)

Comment: Hi Scott, omg thanks!!  I am in preview now, but I got a message. I made an edit and added the SS.